# How to do Receipt Validation in InAppPurchase Ionic 3

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, in-app-purchase

I am using InAppPurchase in our ionic 3 application. I am using the [InAppPurchase2](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/in-app-purchase-2) plugin. I am also using Receipt Validator [Fovea](https://billing.fovea.cc/) for subscription receipt validation. Purchase is working fine if I don't validator. But, the Receipt validator is not working and failing with the following error.

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://validator.fovea.cc/v1/validate?appName=AppNameHere&apiKey=Key here from origin 'http://192.168.0.110:8100' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
store-android.js:1555 [store.js] WARNING: ajax -> request to https://validator.fovea.cc/v1/validate?appName=AppName&apiKey=API Key failed with status 0 ()
store-android.js:1555 [store.js] DEBUG: validator failed, response: "Error 0: "
store-android.js:1555 [store.js] DEBUG: body => undefined
store-android.js:1555 [store.js] DEBUG: verify -> {"success":false,"data":"Error 0: "}
store-android.js:1555 [store.js] DEBUG: verify -> error: "Error 0: "
store-android.js:1555 [store.js] DEBUG: validation failed, no retrying, trigger an error
```

To resolve it I followed the step mentioned in [Fovea Receipt Validator](https://billing-dashboard.fovea.cc/setup/cordova/). I added the following code in my index.html file:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
  content="default-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; connect-src https://validator.fovea.cc; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
```

but Adding it breaks all my application's server request with the following error :

```
Refused to connect to 'Every request URL to server' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "connect-src https://validator.fovea.cc"
```

I have also tried the Cordova whitelist and added all these variations in my config.xml but none of these things works.

```
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="*" />
    <allow-navigation href="*" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://ionic.local/*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <allow-navigation href="*" />
    <access origin="https://validator.fovea.cc" />
    <allow-navigation href="https://validator.fovea.cc/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://validator.fovea.cc/*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://localhost/*" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://192.168.0.110:8100/*" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://localhost" />
```

### Project Info

```
cli packages: (C:\nvm\v10.15.1\node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.4
    Cordova Platforms  : none
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.10

System:

    Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
    Node              : v10.15.1
    npm               : 6.4.1
    OS                : Windows 10
```

### Implementation Code Snippet:

```
    this.iap.validator =
        "https://validator.fovea.cc/v1/validate?appName=AppName&apiKey=ApiKey";

   this.iap.when(productId).approved((product) => {
        product.verify();
    });

    this.iap.when(productId).verified((product) => {
      product.finish();
    });
```

Any Help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please add the error message in text moving forward, so its easier for other to research the error.

Have you registered your app with fovea ? Can you post the code snippet that is verifying this ?

Comment: @DelwynPinto I have updated the question with a text error message and code snippet

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution for the fovea validator failing due to the cors issues. Add the following content security in your index.html and it will work like a charm.

```
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
content="default-src * 'self' https://validator.fovea.cc 'unsafe-inline'  'unsafe-eval'; connect-src * 'self' https://validator.fovea.cc; style-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src ; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; img-src 'self' data: https:;">
```